# Using Django on google colab

Tags: django, google-colaboratory

I am trying to start a new project on djago in google colab.
In order to create a new one, I need to use cmd command line - $ django-admin startproject Project name.
Is there another way to do it?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can run commands by using `!`

you can install django using pip by running:
`!pip install django`

then you would start the project using:
`!django-admin startproject ProjectName`

https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/importing_libraries.ipynb